# Find nearest value in column

Tags: microsoft-excel

Using Excel, in column A I have a list of numbers

```
2156
2029
1990
1975
1874
```

and in cell B1 I have the value 2001.

How do I find the nearest value that matches it in column A? ie 1990 which is A3

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d):

`=INDEX(A1:A5,MATCH(MIN(ABS(A1:A5-B1)),ABS(A1:A5-B1),0))`

Note that as this is an array formula, you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to make this work.